# Why does android.intent.action.MAIN require android.permission.MANAGE_USERS on some devices?

Tags: android-activity

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

The above code works fine but it throws the following exception on an Android 9 device:
Exception: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.amazon.kindle.otter.oobe/.OobeHomeActivity } from ProcessRecord{a28785a 4168:net.biyee.onvifer/u0a32} (pid=4168, uid=10032) requires android.permission.MANAGE_USERS

```
Class: java.lang.SecurityException
 Stack trace: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.amazon.kindle.otter.oobe/.OobeHomeActivity } from ProcessRecord{a28785a 4168:net.biyee.onvifer/u0a32} (pid=4168, uid=10032) requires android.permission.MANAGE_USERS
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1951)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1919)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1869)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:3755)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1669)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4617)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4575)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:735)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4936)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4904)
```

Could anyone shed some light on possible cause?